# Error con submenu en WordPress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, submenu

Estoy creando un plugin y estoy teniendo problemas con el submenu y no sé como solucionarlos.

Este es el script

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'crearmenu');

function crearmenu(){
add_menu_page(
    'Servicio Técnico',
    'Serv. Técnico',
    'manage_options',
    plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'admin/home.php',
    null,
    plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'admin/img/tool.png',
    '1'
);

add_submenu_page(
    plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'admin/nuevo.php',
    'Nuevo',
    'Nuevo',
    'manage_options',
    'Nuevofunc',
    NULL
    );
}
```

No me arroja un error específico, pero la opción `Nuevo` no se ve.
Agradezco de antemano la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

yo estoy usando ACF y tampoco me agregaba el menu desde una función para añadirlo en "Ajustes" desde el functions.php

En el add_action cambie "admin-menu" por "init" y ya me aparece.

Saludos